# Chrome To Phone error "Device not registered for user"

Tags: motorola-droid-2, google-chrome-to-phone

I installed Chrome to Phone on my Droid 2 device and everytime I try to send a webpage to my phone, I get this error "Device not registered for user."

Does anyone have any ideas?

**Additional Information**

Google Chrome version: 11.0.696.77

Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like your phone is using a different google account to attempt to log in to chrome-to-phone. try signing out from the chrome extension, and "Disconnect" the phone from the android app and re-sign in to both.

Answer (score 0):

After you installed chrome2phone on your phone, you need to open the chrome2phone app on your phone and login to your google account.

Then after installing chrome2phone extension in your browser, you also need to login to the same google account.